# Span id not found in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am using Selenium IDE and need to store a span id value:

```
<span id="ustData"
  data-itemId="2130078"></span>     <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I want to store the value "2130078". This value changes for each page but is not visible. I have looked far and wide for a solution.

Currently using xpath location:

```
StoreAtribute
//data-itemId[@span='ustData']
```

From documentation I have read this seems correct?

When I run the test I get: [error] Element //data-itemId[@span='ustData'] not found

Any help would very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath should be:

```
  //span[@id='ustData']
```

to match your **span** tag with an **id attribute** of *'ustData'*

Then if you want to get the `data-itemId` attribute you can do:

```
  //span[@id='ustData']/@data-itemId
```